convert binary string to int in R
I have a bit string represented as a vector of ints. I'm trying to convert this to an integer.
After doing some research, I have seen several related posts, but nothing that addresses this general task. One package called binaryLogic used to do this, but it was removed from CRAN.
For example, if I have a character vector x=c(0,0,0,1), I would like this to become 1.
Ideally, I would like an implementation that can handle a matrix of such vectors and process the conversion in parallel. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
-Paul

What exactly do you have? a string a character vector or a numeric vector? These are doifferent objects

Do you still have the bit strings without their vector representation?

Looking for something like:
#big ending - where the least significant digit is first
x=c(1,0,0,0)

#find the powers of 2
powerOf2 <- 2**(1:length(x) - 1)

#find the sum of x*power of 2s
answer <-sum(x* powerOf2) 
answer

#small ending - where the least significant digit is last
x=c(0,0,0,1)

#find the powers of 2
powerOf2 <- rev(2**(1:length(x) - 1))

#find the sum of x*power of 2s
answer <-sum(x* powerOf2) 
answer


If you have a binary matrix m for example like below, you can use colSums and ^ to convert binary to integers
> colSums(2^(seq_len(ncol(m)) - 1) * t(m))
[1] 21  6 23 12  0 17  8 24

or %*%
> m %*% matrix(2^(seq_len(ncol(m)) - 1))
     [,1]
[1,]   21
[2,]    6
[3,]   23
[4,]   12
[5,]    0
[6,]   17
[7,]    8
[8,]   24


Another approach is using Reduce + asplit
> Reduce(\(x, y) 2 * x + y, rev(asplit(m, 2)))
[1] 21  6 23 12  0 17  8 24

Data Example
> set.seed(0)

> (m <- matrix(sample(0:1, 40, TRUE), 8))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    1    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
[6,]    1    0    0    0    1
[7,]    0    0    0    1    0
[8,]    0    0    0    1    1


Tooting my own horn -- try the package bigBits , which will convert all sorts of stuff to different bases as well as doing Boolean operations.  Works for arbitrarily large binary strings.
